# Непонятное поведение страницы

Tags: php, curl

Добрый день. Есть страница, при переходе на которую проблем не возникает. Страница открывается. Но стоит запросить ее через curl - 404 ответ. Все находится на одном сервере. Если тестировать локально - ошибок нет. Но на сервере постоянная ошибка. 
Сам запрос:

```
$curl = curl_init('http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/parts/search/888');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

В какую сторону копать?

Comment: Страница ваша? может userAgent стоит прописать

Comment: Нет. не помогло

Comment: Проверьте, возвращает ли `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Да, возвращает. Даже с явным указанием адреса не работает

Comment: Апи ведь? Может какие заголовки пропущены, или куки. А 404 из-за неправильного указания кода ошибки пробрасывается например.

Comment: Если дословно, то ответ такой - /parts/search/888 was not found ...

Comment: @IK, может попробовать localhost? Или прописать в hosts на всякий случай. Пока не знаю, что еще попробовать.